# Winapi ListView header divider and LVS_EX_GRIDLINES cell alignment issue

Tags: listview, winapi, windows-10

I'm using a ListView control in a dialog box, whose visual style is set to `LV_VIEW_DETAILS` (report view) and extended visual style is set to `LVS_EX_GRIDLINES`. When executed on Windows 10, the result I get is:

[image: Alignment issue]

As you can see, the header dividers and the vertical lines of the cells surrounding the items are not aligned. There's also no border between the header and the first row.

The problem is also clearly visible in programs that use the same control, such as WinRAR for example:

[image: Alignment issue]

Is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: `LVS_EX_GRIDLINES` is buggy and always has been.

Answer (score 0):

Since the replies to this problem were unhelpful I decided to look for a solution myself. For anyone who encounters this in the future, here is a solution for x64 applications that fixes the bug inside of comctl32.dll (this is version specific). Make sure you are using LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER.

```
[ENABLE]
alloc(newmem,128)
label(returnhere)
label(originalcode)
label(exit)

newmem:
cmp r14,0
jne originalcode
push rax
lea rax,[rsp+88]
dec dword ptr [rax+4]
pop rax

originalcode:
mov rbx,[rsp+30]
mov rsi,[rsp+38]
add rsp,20

exit:
jmp returnhere

comctl32.DSA_Create+105F:
jmp newmem
returnhere:

[DISABLE]
dealloc(newmem)
comctl32.DSA_Create+105F:
mov rbx,[rsp+30]
mov rsi,[rsp+38]
add rsp,20
```

This is for version 6.10.19041.1052 of comctl32.dll, but you should be able to scan this AoB to find the address used in the script a few lines above the result.

```
BA 0B 12 00 00 48 FF 15
```